# не стабильная работа AppS Script для гугл таблиц

Tags: google-apps-script

Имеется 2 скрипта:
1:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() !== "Холодный поиск") return;
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if(activeCell.getColumn() >= 13 && activeCell.getColumn() <= 15) {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, "GMT+7", "HH:mm, dd.MM.yyyy");
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), 12);
    targetCell.setValue(date);
  } else if(activeCell.getColumn() === 16) {
    activeCell.getRow().setBackground("#808080");
  } else if (activeCell.getColumn() === 17) {
    activeCell.getRow().setBackground("#ff0000"); 
  }
}
```

И второй

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if(sheet.getName() !== "Клиенты") return;
  var activeCell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if(activeCell.getColumn() === 3) {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, "GMT+7", "HH:mm, dd.MM.yyyy");
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), 2);
    targetCell.setValue(date);
  } else if (activeCell.getColumn() >= 4 && activeCell.getColumn() <= 15) {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = Utilities.formatDate(now, "GMT+7", "HH:mm, dd.MM.yyyy");
    var targetCell = sheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), 1);
    targetCell.setValue(date);
  }
}
```

Скрип работает с перебоями, иногда работает идеально (позавчера все работало когда прописал его) сегодня зашел в таблицу перестал работать и тот и другой. В таблице 2 пользователя создатель и редактор, проблема на том и другом. И еще в Сводка за 7 дней
Частота появления ошибок
9.91% % выполнений с ошибками
Количество выполнений 454.
В чем может быть проблема, нужно ли дополнительно прописать какие то триггеры для корректного выполнения ?

Comment: А есть описание ошибок? Какую именно ошибку выдают ваши скрипты?

Comment: Я к сожалению не знаю как посмотреть ошибки.

Answer (score 0):

Создай триггер на изменение руками и привяжи к функции например onEdit_custom. Триггеры по именам onEdit и тд часто глючат.

- ты по условию что то красишь? может условное форматирование  попробовать?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как должен выглядеть код для подобного триггера ? У меня банальный скрипт при изменении значения ячейки, или отметки чекбокса(галочку ставлю) скрипт должен проставлять даты в отдельные ячейки, это основное что требуется и дополнительно закрашивать строку. И кстати эта часть скрипта не работала совсем (работала первая часть с простановкой даты) почему не срабатывала закраска я тоже не понял. Но мне это не сильно нужно, просто для удобства визуального восприятия

Comment: Кажется чтото получилось. Я создал триггер для функции он эдит кастом(развертывание - основное резервирование, событие - из таблицы при изменении). соответственно скрипт добавил с этой функцией (создал третий фаил со скриптом аналог того что выше под номером 1 просто заменил название функции) вроде работает пока что... И там же я увидел где посмотреть ошибки, по поводу закраски пишет следующее: 3 февр. 2023 г., 01:34:31 Ошибка TypeError: activeCell.getRow(...).setBackground is not a function
    at onEdit_custom(Кастом:11:21)

Comment: Нашел решение. переписал скрипт следующим образом теперь работает как планировалось. 
} else if(activeCell.getColumn() === 16) {
  sheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#808080");
} else if (activeCell.getColumn() === 17) {
  sheet.getRange(activeCell.getRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).setBackground("#ff0000"); 
}
}

Comment: Всем спасибо. на данном этапе все работает. если проблема вернется напишу)